# How can i create a Mono with 3 or more different clients sources?

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux

I'm trying to make a BFF that returns 3 attributes from 3 different clients, the response should look like this: Mono<ExampleClass'>:

```
{
   name: "Exemple",   // <- nameClient
   value: 20.0,       // <- valueClient
   otherValue: 25.0   // <- otherValueClient
}
```

I tried to do this:

```
return nameClient
        .getName(clientId)
        .zipWith( valueClient.getValue(id))
        .zipWith( otherValueClient.getOtherValue(id))
        .map {   
            Product(it.t1.t1.name, it.t1.t2.value, it.t2.otherValue) }
        }
```

The problem is that i'm getting a tuple with other tuple inside: Tuple2<Tuple2<value,value>,value> and i'm not getting the second value of inside tuple.
Is there another way to build better this response?

Comment: Please, clarify types of `clientId` and `id` and method `valueClient.getValue`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the static method of `zip` in the `Mono` class

```
Mono.zip(nameClient,valueClient,otherValueClient)
```

This will give you a `Tuple3` when all three `Mono`s complete

If you need one Mono to complete, in order to use it's value in following Mono's, but still want to zip them all together you could do something like the following

```
    nameClient
        .getName(clientId)
        .flatMap(name ->
            Mono.zip(
                Mono.just(name),
                valueClient.getValue(name),
                otherValueClient.getValue(name)
            )
        )
```